# Suppose that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ , and differentiable on $(a,b)$, if $f'(x)>0$ on $(a,b)$ , Which of the following is necessarily true?

Tags: calculus

Suppose  that $f$  is continuous on $[a,b]$ , and differentiable on $(a,b)$, if $f'(x)>0$  on $(a,b)$ , 
Which of the following is necessarily true?

$\text{(A) $f$ has no local extrema on $(a,b)$} \quad\\
\text{(B) $f$ is decreasing on $[a,b]$} \quad\\
\text{(C) $f$ is a constant function on $(a,b)$ } \quad\\
\text{(D) $f$ is concave up on $(a,b)$} \quad\\$

Clearly  $B$ and $C$  isn't true , what's about $A, D$?

Comment: So what is your thinking on this?

Comment: Any thoughts?  Surely you can eliminate some of the options?

Comment: $B, C $ is not necessarily true , but what is about $A, D$?

Comment: Well, try to find counterexamples.  Can you draw a concave down, increasing function on $[0,1]$, say?  If  $c$, with $a<c<b$ is a local min or max, what do you know about $f'(c)$?

Comment: @ lulu Got it , A is the answer, since the there is not conversion of sign $f'(x)$ on any x belong to (a,b)

Answer (score 0):

in order to answer this queston, one must know the applications of calculus. As you said B and C aren't always true, so we are left with A and D. We know that f'(x) > 0, and the theory says that if f'(x) > 0 on an interval, the function has no local extrema there. We use the second derivative f''(x) in order to find out if the function is concave or convexe, I would like to explain here the mechanism behind it, but I don't know if I'm competent enough, I recommend you watch some Youtube videos, or if you have calculus books, read from them.